# Convert localized string to float in C

Tags: c

I have float number in `char[]`. It's `DE` or `PL` localized string, and has `','` not `'.'` as decimal separator. Is there any standard way to convert such string to float? I'm looking for something better then "replace , with . and use `atoi`".

Comment: may be `strtod()` will help you ... http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod

Comment: Just replace the "," by"." and use atof().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Omkant suggested, `strtod()` will do for you:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8");
errno = 0;
val = strtod(myString, &endPtr);
if (errno)
{
    // Handle error
}
if (*endPtr)
{
    // This tells you that the string had a trail, e.g. "250.99USD"
}
```

You can use a NULL instead of &endPtr, and if you are sure that you'll never attempt to convert zeroes, you can use `val` being zero to check for errors instead of setting `errno`:

```
// Faster, sloppier version
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8");
if (!(val = strtod(myString, NULL)))
{
    // An error occurred, provided myString was not legitimately zero
    // AND is not so large a value as to create overflow.
}
```

In some contexts the slightly more expensive **sscanf** will be better, because `strtod` can accept alternative number formats such as hexadecimal. In some cases you might *not* want to allow something that's not a "proper" float, e.g. 3.14159, to make it past the conversions stage; `strtod()` will allow it.

Also, `strtod()` will accept (and in the sloppier version, **not detect**) strings such as "INFERIOR" (which will be interpreted as INFinity with a tail of ERIOR). Not really likely, but in some contexts it could lead to an application vulnerability if the value is under the user's control.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, both [sscanf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) and [strtod(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) should take care of [locale](http://linux.die.net/man/7/locale)s. Call [setlocale(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) appropriately before.